# How to detect a Prepared Transaction inside a trigger

Tags: postgresql, transactions, postgresql-9.2

I have a problem with existing database code (a trigger) that call a function trigger that use the [NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-notify.html) command, which is not supported in the context of a [prepared transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html).

My question is simple : from the function trigger, is there a way to detect that we are in the context of a prepared transaction ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect that the current transaction will be committed using prepared transactions and two-phase commit, because you haven't `PREPARE`d the transaction yet; the transaction has no idea it's going to be subjected to two-phase commit until after your trigger runs. PostgreSQL doesn't require that you `BEGIN TRANSACTION FOR TWO PHASE COMMIT` (imaginary syntax) or anything like that.

You can test for `max_prepared_transactions` > 0 in `pg_settings` to see if prepared transactions are *enabled*, but there's no way to know if 2PC will be used until it happens.

Comment: Of course :-) So I will need to remove the call to NOTIFY. The error message is 'cannot PREPARE a transaction that has executed LISTEN, UNLISTEN or NOTIFY.

Comment: @omatrot As a hackish workaround you can use `dblink` to send the `NOTIFY` via another connection. This won't be transactional, though; if the main transaction rolls back, the notify is still sent, and the notify arrives before the main transaction commits.

Comment: @omatrot It's probably technically possible to support delivery of `NOTIFY` messages in prepared transactions, just not implemented yet.